# If a AWS Lambda function has event sources from multiple Kinesis streams, will the batch of incoming records be from a single Kinesis stream or a mix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

The title might be a bit confusing. I'll try my best to make it clearer.

Suppose I have a AWS Lambda function that has two different Kinesis streams A and B as input event sources.

So, for the below, since a KinesisEvent instance contains a batch of records, will the batch contain records from a single stream, or essentially it contain records from both streams A and B?

```
public class ProcessKinesisEvents {
    public void recordHandler(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each mapping between an [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) stream and an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function is a dedicated entity resulting from a call to [CreateEventSourceMapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html) and comprised of the [EventSourceArn](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-CreateEventSourceMapping-request-EventSourceArn) and the [FunctionName](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-CreateEventSourceMapping-request-FunctionName), for which you also specify a dedicated [Batch Size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-CreateEventSourceMapping-request-BatchSize) accordingly:

```js
POST /2015-03-31/event-source-mappings/ HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
    "BatchSize": number,
    "Enabled": boolean,
    "EventSourceArn": "string",
    "FunctionName": "string",
    "StartingPosition": "string"
}
```

Consequently, the batches you will receive are constrained to the single event source that constitutes the resp. mapping, and each other event source will yield a separate invocation of your Lambda function accordingly, so everything is properly isolated.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.

Comment: Any idea why the API has the event source on the record and not the KinesisEvent?